# How do I get lines with a range of number?

Tags: bash, filter, sed, awk

I have a text file like this:

```
    1.1    2.4   10.1
    5.6   10.5    2.9
   10.8   29.2   -2.1
   12.7   29.1   -2.1
   15.2   38.5   -5.2
   25.0   41.1  -19.1
```

Now, I would like to obtain the lines which its 1st-column has number less than 15 using awk, sed, or any other commands. Anybody knows?
It must produce:

```
  1.1    2.4   10.1
  5.6   10.5    2.9
 10.8   29.2   -2.1
 12.7   29.1   -2.1
```

Comment: I usually start with `man awk`

Comment: thanks. I should look more next time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
awk '$1<15' input_file
```

#### Test:

```
[jaypal:~/Temp] cat f
1.1    2.4   10.1
5.6   10.5    2.9
10.8   29.2   -2.1
12.7   29.1   -2.1
15.2   38.5   -5.2
25.0   41.1  -19.1
[jaypal:~/Temp] awk '$1<15' f
1.1    2.4   10.1
5.6   10.5    2.9
10.8   29.2   -2.1
12.7   29.1   -2.1
```

Comment: @Raa You're welcome. Here is a good tutorial link on `awk` if you wish to learn. http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Awk.html

Comment: @Raa It's a good starter point. Big daddy is this --> http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html

Answer (score 3):

Awk is simplest:

```
awk '$1 < 15' filename
```

Answer (score 1):

```
perl -lane 'print if($F[0] <15)' your_file
```